# Get datatable row when dynamically generating colulmns in Primeng

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using primeng datatable and dynamically generating the columns. I would like to call the method `getRowMarking(data[col.field])` and pass a row to it but it doesn't work like that. Is it possible to get one row when creating the dynamic columns? Cause `data[col.field]` doesn't work.

simple datatable:

```
 <p-dataTable [value]="data" scrollable="true" sortMode="multiple" editable="true">
    <p-column *ngFor="let col of header" [filter]="true" [sortable]="true" [editable]="col.editable" [style]="{'width':'150px'}"
      [field]="col.field" [header]="col.field" [ngStyle]="getRowMarking(data[col.field])"></p-column>
  </p-dataTable>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the entire row from each column, here is how you can achieve this by using templating :

```
<p-dataTable [value]="data" scrollable="true" sortMode="multiple" editable="true">
  <p-column *ngFor="let col of cols" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header">
    <ng-template let-row="rowData" let-i="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
      <span [ngStyle]="getRowMarking(col.field, row)">
        {{row[col.field]}}
      </span>
    </ng-template>
  </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Here in `getRowMarking`, you now have access to column and row from each cell of your table.

So you can apply conditional style for instance :

```
getRowMarking(col, row) {
    if(col==='year') {
      if(row.year<=2010) {
        return {'color':'red'};
      }
      return {'color':'green'};
    }
    else if(col==='color') {
      return {'color':row.color};
    }
  }
```

See [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Rb02FXJk53YoIC2Rc9sD?p=preview)

Is that what you want ?

Comment: not bad but I have realized that it is not a good approach to set style via a method cause it will be called each time when html state changes.